# Showing error while installing BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

while pip installing BeautifulSoup it is showing this:-

```
C:\Users\LENOVO>pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in 
c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2; python_version >= "3.0" in 
c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.0.1)

C:\Users\LENOVO>
```

But while importing this library it is showing this error message:-

```
>>>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
>>>
```

I have only Python3 installed in my system. Please Help :-)

Comment: I think you have it installed on `anaconda` `env` `c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` and are you running that code `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` on your windows `cmd`?

Comment: yes, then what should I do?

Comment: Hello! so you have installed your `bs4` on your anaconda env but you're running it on your windows `cmd` which also you have installed python? I think what you need to do is go to your anaconda env type `conda activate name_of_env` then do that `import` for `bs4`

Answer (score 0):

Python loads modules from location in sys.path.  So probably worth calling that and seeing where it is looking for modules.  E.g. for my system (in a virtualenv)

```
In [9]: sys.path
Out[9]:
['/Users/me/.virtualenvs/standard/bin',
 '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/standard/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/standard/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/standard/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '',
 '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/standard/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/standard/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/me/.ipython']
```

and checking that `c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` is in that list

Comment: it is already installed on anaconda env, thats why I am not being able to install it in my system, but when I am importing BeautifulSoup into my program it is showing error, so what steps should I follow now?

Comment: if it's installed on your anaconda env then I think you need to go to that environment and do the imports check [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)